# Разделение рабочего стола на 4 части окнами Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане.
Раньше на работе сидел на Росе, и была там полезная фишка у рабочего стола можно было, подводя окно к углу рабочего стола - окно оставалось там.
Сейчас поставил убунту в ней можно подводить окно только к левому и правому краю рабочего стола.
Можно ли сделать так же как в Росе?
P.S.Прошу прощения за такое описание, не знаю как эта фишка называется.

Comment: А можно дополнить описание? Сложно понять пожелание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеете в виду расположение окон симметричное, попробуйте `ctrl+alt+цифры` (на цифровой клавиатуре).
Возможно, вам поможет [топик](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=49963.0)

Comment: Действительно, спасибо, не знал.